# convexity proof

Tags: convex-analysis, nonlinear-system

Suppose $X \subset R^n$ is a convexe set and $f : X \rightarrow R^1$ with $f \in C^1/X$.

How to prove that $f$ is a convexe function on $X$ iff ($\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y))^T(x-y)\geq0$ for any$x,y\in X$

Comment: What does $f \in C^1 / X$ mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\phi(t) = f(y+t(x-y))$, then $\phi$ is differentiable.

Suppose $f$ is convex. Then $\phi'$ is non decreasing and so $\phi'(1) -\phi'
(0) \ge 0$.

Since $\phi'(t) = \langle \nabla f (y +t (x-y)), x-y \rangle $, we have the desired result.

Now suppose the gradient condition holds. This implies that 
$\phi'$ is non decreasing, and so $\phi$ is convex and hence, since $x,y$ are arbitrary, $f$ is convex.

Note that only differentiability is required.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, there something I didn't understand in your solution, why did you put the ϕ(1)−ϕ(0)≥0 ? does that mean that $f(x)-f(y) \geq0$ ? and for what purpose?

Comment: Sorry, I  meant $\phi'(1)-\phi'(0) \ge 0$, will correct...

Comment: okey thanks for your help appreciate!!